# SQL Server Computed Column Trim

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a computed column to an SQL database. The Computed Column Specification looks like this.

```
BusinessName + ' ' + Surname + ' ' + FirstName
```

which works fine.

Often the BusinessName is blank, so I want to Trim it.

```
Trim(BusinessName + ' ' + Surname + ' ' + FirstName)
```

But when I do I get an error

Comment: There is no trim() instead use ltrim() | rtrim()

Comment: Specify columns datatype

Comment: @AlexK. There is from 2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql

Comment: @AlexK. TRIM() is there, you're referring to older version(s)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below logic,

First option: check if value is null, replace it by empty string, you will have leading empty space if BusinessName is null

```
isnull(BusinessName, '') + ' ' + Surname + ' ' + FirstName
```

or

Second option: check if BusinessName is empty or null, do not take into account if so. You won't have leading empty space if BusinessName is null or empty

```
case when isnull(BusinessName, ' ') <> ' '
    then BusinessName + ' ' + Surname + ' ' + FirstName
else Surname + ' ' + FirstName
end as FullName
```

Comment: Your second solution is more elegant, as the former will have a leading space in the event that the BusinessName is NULL/blank. Good Answer.

Comment: @Eli, Thanks,  you're absolutrly right, I would use second option as well.

Comment: `isnull(BusinessName + ' ', '') + Surname + ' ' + FirstName`

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends by column datatypes and constraints.   A more general approach could be the following.  Starting from this if as a rule SURNAME and NAME (for instance) are not NULLABLE and cannot be blank, you can omit some of the functions:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (BUSIN_NAME VARCHAR(20), SURNAME VARCHAR(20), NAME VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(NULL, 'A', NULL);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(NULL, 'B ', NULL);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('', 'Karl ', ' Smith');
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('Dr.', 'Karl ', ' Smith');
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('Dr.  ', 'Joe ', '   Martin   ');

SELECT BUSIN_NAME, SURNAME, NAME
    , LTRIM(RTRIM( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(BUSIN_NAME,'')))+ ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(SURNAME,'')))+' ' +LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(NAME,''))))) DESCR
    , DATALENGTH ( LTRIM(RTRIM( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(BUSIN_NAME,'')))+ ' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(SURNAME,'')))+' ' +LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(NAME,''))))) ) AS LENGTH
    FROM @T
```

OUtput:

```
BUSIN_NAME  SURNAME NAME    DESCR             LENGTH
NULL        NULL    NULL                        0
NULL        A       NULL    A                   1
NULL        B       NULL    B                   1
            Karl     Smith  Karl Smith          10
Dr.         Karl     Smith  Dr. Karl Smith      14
Dr.         Joe        Martin       Dr. Joe Martin  14
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the following:

```
select stuff( (coalesce(' ' + BusinessName, '') +
               coalesce(' ' + Surname, '') +
               coalesce(' ' + Firstname, '')
              ), 1, 1, '')
```

These easily generalizes to more fields.  You can use `ltrim()` rather than `stuff()`, because you are using spaces as a separator.  `stuff()` is more general, because it handles other separators (notably commas).

As a computed column:

```
alter table t add newcol as 
    (stuff( (coalesce(' ' + BusinessName, '') +
             coalesce(' ' + Surname, '') +
             coalesce(' ' + Firstname, '')
            ), 1, 1, ''
          )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
isnull(BusinessName + ' ', '') + isnull(Surname + ' ', '') + FirstName
```

It relies on the fact that concatenating a string to a NULL value is still NULL, so `BusinessName + ' '` will resolve as NULL if `BusinessName` is NULL. We then coalesce this to an empty string and the extra leading space is lost.